# Determining parameters in AR model for non-stationary time series

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, stationarity

I am currently trying to fit an AR model to some financial data. The time series $Y_t$ in levels is clearly non-stationary; however it appears the first differences $dY_t$ are stationary (and this is backed up by the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test). I have therefore determined the order $p$ of the AR model using $dY_t$.

I now want to estimate the $p$ model parameters by minimising some objective function (e.g. sum of square residuals). Should this minimisation be with respect to the original (level) data or the differenced data? In other words, do I choose my parameters such that the square residuals between the fitted model and $dY_t$ are minimised, or do I choose them so that, after 'undifferencing'  the model, the square residuals are minimised w.r.t. $Y_t$?

(By 'undifferencing' I mean taking the fitted values of the AR model and adding them successively to $Y_{t=0}$)

I know this can all be handled automatically by using an ARIMA implementation in a software package - this is more to improve my understanding of what's going on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do estimation with transformed data.